# How to assign the function return value to a variable after a click for later use in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, what I want is to save the function return value on a variable for later use for example, just to save it, but after clicking, say on a button. For example, we have:

```
let x = 3;    
function foo(){
        let z = 5;
        z = x + 3;
        return z;
    }
```

Now, if I write:

```
let hold = foo();
```

it will keep the return value, but I want this to be saved on "hold" after click, by using something like this:

```
document.getElementById("empty_field").onclick = function() {foo()};
```

Here, the click calls the function, but it does not save the return value anywhere. How can I save it on a variable?

Comment: `var hold; document.getElementById("empty_field").onclick = function() {hold = foo()};` I think `let` limits it to the scope of the function. How about define `var hold` somewhere outside the function, then in the function assign the return value of `foo()` to `hold`

Comment: @varlogtim No reason to use `var`, `let`'s block scope and non-hoisting is more intuitive

Comment: You may want to look at data-binding via a tool like [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).  Knockout sets up a Javascript object that is "bound" to your HTML form.  Changes in the form are reflected in the object, changes in the object are displayed on the form.  It is pretty easy to use and lets you have a "model" or object that holds the data being displayed and edited.

Comment: The code above is just an example. let or var does not really matter at this point. The solution {hold = foo() } saves the return value on "hold", but I can't use this "hold" somewhere else in the code. I want to be able to use this "hold" whenever and wherever I want and not to be limited within those { } brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't

Long Answer: You can leverage the concept of scope to your advantage by simply declaring `hold` prior to setting it's value. Here's what it would look like.

```
let x = 3;
let hold; //variable is declared here so the click function has access to it.    
function foo(){
        let z = 5;
        z = x + 3;
        return z;
    }

document.getElementById("empty_field").onclick = function() {
    hold = foo()
};
```

Longer Answer: You can access or modify `hold` anywhere within the scope that the variable was declared. Let's add another function where we modify `hold` again.

```
let x = 3;
let hold; //variable is declared here so the click function has access to it.    
function foo(){
        let z = 5;
        z = x + 3;
        return z;
    }

document.getElementById("empty_field").onclick = function() {
    hold = foo()
};

document.getElementById("increment").onclick = function(){
    hold++;  //this the same as hold = hold + 1
}
```

This is also valid because these click functions are being defined in the same scope that `hold` was defined in. It's good to avoid using globally scoped variables. So you may consider using a constructor and just passing the object between functions as an argument like so...

```
function myConstructor(){
    //initialize
    this.hold = 0
    this.foo = function(x){
        let z = 5;
        z = x + 3;
        this.hold = z;
    }
    this.increment = function(){
        this.hold++;
    }
}

let x = 3;
let myObj = new myConstructor() //I know my naming sucks just bear with me lol

document.getElementById("empty_field").onclick = function() {
    myObj.foo(x) //x is still available since it was declared globally
    console.log(myObj.hold);
};

document.getElementById("increment").onclick = function(){
    myObj.increment();
    console.log(myObj.hold);
}
```

Anyways that's the long and short of it. As always, there are many, many ways of doing things and there's not an absolute correct way. I just thought it might be helpful to know of a few options. More reading about constructors can be done here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

Comment: Yes, it worked. I just did'n think about it that we can write "function() {
    hold = foo()'. Thank you

Comment: but still there is a problem. it is working when we do other operations inside { } those brackets, but what if I want to use the "hold" somewhere else in my code.  Say, at some point I want to increment the "hold"? Is there any solution?

Comment: Sure, I added a longer answer to my initial answer if you want to check it out @Suren